# SerialPort Latency between Unity & Arduino caused by readBytesUntil

Tags: unity-game-engine, serial-port, arduino

I have created a game with the unity game engine and have two way serial communication with an arduino. I can send data to Unity using Serial.println without any problem. However when I try and send a letter to Arduino from Unity I am getting incredible latency. The latency is being caused by the following code. It slows down the entire game and also slows down the data being sent to unity from Arduino.

```
  {
   int lf = 10;
   Serial.readBytesUntil(lf, myCol, 1);
   if(strcmp(myCol,"A")==0){
   digitalWrite(StimPin, HIGH);       
   }
```

I have read that serial ports can't read/write without causing latency. If this is so can anyone recommend a workaround to have two way communication between arduino & unity without lag ?
Thanks
Joey

Comment: If you send only a single letter from Unity then you must use Serial.read().  Using Serial.readBytesUntil() like that is only suitable for reading a string terminated by a linefeed, it will take a full second to timeout.

Comment: Thanks Hans - that eliminates the latency the only issue now is that I am getting an error:
 "IOException: Resource busy"

Comment: That's obviously not an error that's ever raised by the code you posted.  You need a clairvoyant, not a programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change approach, I had a project with unity and creating a custom string was much faster than sending.
In the Arduino side, try to loop for each char and re-create the string and in the Unity side have a secondary thread looping for any incoming char.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue by simply putting timeout to 100ms:

```
Serial.setTimeout(100);
```

Reference:
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/SetTimeout